# AdMob in Eclipse/ failing instantiatet com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adview

i have a Problem and nothing helps me... :(

i got this error every time..

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

here u can see it:

[Problem to see](https://www.dropbox.com/s/twiuro327vfxyr7/Screenshot%20%2816%29.png)

here is my code:

**mainactivity.java**

```
 package com.example.test;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  　 publicclass MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 @Override
protectedvoid onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest); } 　 @Override
publicboolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 returntrue;
 } @Override
publicboolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
 if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
 returntrue;
 } returnsuper.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 } }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.blackcalculator.MainActivity">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1322203023519977/3000186843">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?
xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>


<
manifestxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


package="com.example.test"


android:versionCode="1"


android:versionName="1.0">


<uses-sdk


android:minSdkVersion="9"


android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>


<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application


android:allowBackup="true"


android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"


android:label="@string/app_name"


android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


<meta-dataandroid:name="com.google.android.gms.version"


android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


<activity


android:name=".MainActivity"


android:label="@string/app_name">


<intent-filter>


<actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>


<categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>


</intent-filter>


</activity>


<activityandroid:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"


android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout| uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


</application>


</
manifest>
```

i also found out something in the adview eems wrong, look in the right side

[look here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt6w2e28bhhffjk/Screenshot%20%2818%29.png)

i hope u can help mee ...

Comment: So did you follow the instructions and look at the error log for more details? What were those details?

Comment: when i click on the error log nothing happens.
when i click on open class this is what i get:

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt6w2e28bhhffjk/Screenshot%20%2818%29.png)

Comment: Do you mean there *is* no error log? Additionally, please edit your manifest to format it more pleasantly - there's no need to have a blank line between each *useful* line, and no indentation at all...

Comment: yes there are no Problems or something else...

Comment: sorry the manifest to the manifest of copy Problems :P
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt6w2e28bhhffjk/Screenshot%20%2818%29.png)

thats the one error i can figuard out which is an red class Thing but eclipse say nothing

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow that comment *at all*, but you should still edit the manifest *in your post* to be more readable - that's what I was talking about before.

Comment: here is good example for AdMob http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.com/2013/08/android-admob-sample-code.html

Comment: yes i use admob and the example is my projec, i've made all the same..